# How to do url matching with wildcard in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match a given url against a set of filtering conditions based on which the url will be accepted or discarded. Here's a sample pattern

```
http://test.blogs.com/between_the/
http://test.blogs.com/between_the/page*
http://test.blogs.com/between_the/archives*
*index.html*
*/page/*
http://abc.blogs.com/
http://area.test.com/index.php/blogs_a/blog_list/
http://area.test.com/index.php/blogs_b/blog_list/*/
```

Based on the condition, the following urls will be accepted

```
http://test.blogs.com/between_the/2012/02/autocad-ws-update-coming.html
http://abc.blogs.com/test
http://area.test.com/index.php/blogs_b/blog_list/page/2
```

while the ones below will be filtered

```
http://test.blogs.com/between_the/page/2
http://test.blogs.com/index.html
http://area.test.com/index.php/blogs_b/blog_list/1/
```

Just wondering what's the best approach for this ? I'm not sure if this can be handled using a complex generic regex as the exclusion patterns are not predictable. I was thinking of removing the wildcards and create two seperate List for exact match and contains match, then have the input url iterate against the two lists.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a List of regular expressions and accept a url when it doesn't match any of the regexes. A url is discarded as soon as it matches a regex. This should be much easier and more maintainable than creating a single complex regular expression.

Comment: thanks for your input. That surely is a way to deal, but I was trying to avoid it since the number of patterns can be big, which will end up creating a regex pattern for each of them. Moreover, the list will be growing. Maybe, due to my lack of experience of regex, I was looking to explore one generic regex pattern or any other ways to deal besides regex. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @Shamik If you are looking for a more sophisticated solution, what you can do is make a hierarchy of prefix-suffix patterns, for e.g. domains at the first level and sub-directories at lower levels. That way you can manage the increasing number of patterns and still have a relatively efficient matching process.